# Issue with bootstrap responsiveness - overlapping of image and text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, responsiveness

When changing the size of the internet browser, everything seems to be responsive until get to a certain window size. When expanding my window, the container size of my site will jump from (944px X 240px) to (463.5px x 289px). Please help me figure out how to solve the overlapping issue!

This is what it looks like, while expanding it, and before it overlaps:
[image]

This is what it looks like, while expanding it, and it jumps to a smaller container and overlap:

[image]

If I keep expanding it, the container goes back to a normal size again and responsiveness looks good once again: 
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" >
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <img src="/assets/img/blank_avatar.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" class="img-circle"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <h2>Title</h2>
                                <h4>Testing header here</h4>
                                <h4>Testing header here</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <span>Face</span>
                                            <i class="icon-grin"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <span>Face</span>
                                            <i class="icon-neutral"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <span>Star</span>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <a class="btn btn-default btn" href="#">
                                    <i class="icon-neutral"></i>test
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0z8quprn/embedded/result/)**.
I think it works as you expect it to now.
I removed on `div` that held some bootstrap classes and placed the classes in the `div` below the `div` I removed. And added full set of classes. If you just use the smaller classes you can lose control as it resizes.

Now when you resize it looks to work fine.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" >
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-wcJ9gRjTTRY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/XuTCJHDodX4/photo.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" class="img-circle"/>
                </div>
                    <div class="container-fluid col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <h2>Title</h2>
                                <h4>Testing header here</h4>
                                <h4>Testing header here</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 block">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <span>Face</span>
                                            <i class="icon-grin"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <span>Face</span>
                                            <i class="icon-neutral"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <span>Star</span>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <a class="btn btn-default btn" href="#">
                                    <i class="icon-neutral"></i>test
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much I knew I had to have something wrong, but could not figure out what to remove or add to remedy the situation. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is that you're declaring a container inside a container and that might be causing the problem. If you give the first dive that contains everything the calss container-fluid that should be good to go for you. I would probably start getting of that and the second .row classed div since you want to have everything inline and then collapsing vertically.